# How to determine the fundamental period of this discrete time function?

Tags: trigonometry, signal-processing, periodic-functions

> How to determine the fundamental period of this discrete time function? $$x[n]=cos(0.6\pi n)$$

To find a period, I do $$\cos(0.6\pi n)=(0.6\pi n + 0.6\pi N),$$
where both $n$ and $N$ have to be integers.

Now, you need to have $$0.6\pi N=2\pi k.$$ So you have $$N=\frac{2}{0.6}k,$$ and $k$ has to be an integer. What is the fundamental period and why?

Comment: `To find a period, I do` Why? That makes no sense, the $n$'s on the two sides are not the same. What you could do, instead, is $\,0.6 n \pi = 0.6 n' \pi + 2k \pi\,$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$N = \frac{2}{0.6}k=\frac{10}{3}k.$$
Since both $N$ and $k$ are  integers, $k$ must be a multiple of $3$. Hence, the smallest positive integer of the form $\frac{10}{3}k$ is 
$$N = \frac{10\times 3}{3}=10.$$

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I was wondering why it cannot be 2.

Comment: @user132522 If $N=2$ then $k$ would be $0.6$, which is not an integer.